# coffeescript angular function call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, haml

I have a referral link that I'd like to be able to share, but I'm wondering if I can embed a variable in a function call that's already being literal.

In my controller:

```
$scope.get_share_link = (link) ->
  text = "http://www.whatever.com/share?u=" + encodeURIComponent(link)
  text
```

In my view (coffeescript).

```
%a{:href=>"{{ get_share_link(link_url) }}"}
  share
```

Can I do this? Currently I'm getting `http://www.whatever.com/share?u=link` which is, of course, not resolving `link`.

Comment: again, only use double quotes if you're using string interpolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, sorted. I was watching the egghead.io videos and I wasn't aware of filters to be used like function calls! Now I feel silly.

```
%a{:href=>"http://www.whatever.com/u={{link | encodeURIComponent}}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I'm not sure if you can do what you've wrote, But I'm pretty sure this works.

```
$scope.get_share_link = function(link) {
    return 'http://www.whatever.com/share?u=' + encodeURIComponent(link);
};
```

then:

```
$scope.get_share_link("myurl")
```

returns: `http://www.whatever.com/share?u=myurl`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have $scope.link_url some where

```
 $scope.link_url = "http://google.com"

 $scope.get_share_link = (link) ->
   "http://www.whatever.com/share?u=" + encodeURIComponent(link)
```

Check here for working example http://jsbin.com/esuRIZo/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: CoffeeScript interpolates double quoted strings so you should only use them in situations where you plan to use variables or expressions in a string. Funny enough, your 2nd string would be perfect for that, `"http://www.whatever.com/share?u=#{encodeURLComponent(link)}"`. However, your first string should really be single quotes.

Comment: `link_url` already exists. It's specific to each of the entries, so `link_url` will be different for each instance of `ng-repeat`. It's not under the global scope.